# Bind the selected values to the checkbox in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a php code snippet mentioned below

```
 <?php  $query = "SELECT * FROM Qualification";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
   ?>   
<input type='checkbox' value='"<?php $row['Id'] ?> "' name='Qualification[]' /><?php  $row['Description'] ?><br>

<?php } ?>
```

This above Code is used to Display all the qualification from the databases .

Output will be

```
[] Teacher
[] Engineer
[] Doctor
[] Banker etc..
```

Now say i have checked 3 checkboxes **Teacher,Engineer,Doctor.**

```
foreach($_POST['Qualification'] as $Qualification) 
         {
            $AllQualification .=$Qualification.",";
         }

$AllQualification ="1,2,3,"
```

So i am concatenating the ID of the values into a string and store it in database as
**1,2,3,**

Now i need to bind the datas again to that checkbox. When i am retriving the **selected qualification it gives 1,2,3,**

Now How to bind the selectedvalues to the checkbox.

***The output i need is teacher,Engineer,Doctor should be checked 
and banker should be uncheked.***

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to concatenate them as a string? Doesn't an array work?

Comment: yes i need to concatenate and store it as string . I am storing it in database

Comment: I would recommend imploding the array, and filtering out bad values too. Safer and you get rid of the last comma ( http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dadd320e6ba72ea705b756cce5b41955cc9ab2a3 ). You might also want to check out the MySQL SET data type, as it may be a better solution and has some handy query support such as FIND_IN_SET which could come in handy later (i.e. if you want to find all teachers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

explode the string to array

```
$AllQualification ="1,2,3,";

$selected  = explode(",", $AllQualification);
$selected = array_filter($selected);
//print_r($selected);
```

using in_array you can check whether it is checked

```
<?php  $query = "SELECT * FROM Qualification";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
  ?>   
<input type='checkbox' value='"<?php $row['Id'] ?> "' name='Qualification[]' 
    <?php if (in_array($row['Id'], $selected)){ echo "checked" } ?> /><?php  $row['Description'] ?><br>

         <?php } ?>
```

check this link http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae6bbfc6bd0ad84ddceadeac608fa6747de41274