# Binded values of checkbox is not storing into array

Tags: php, arrays

This post is regarding my previous question continuation
[Bind values to checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562301/bind-the-selected-values-to-the-checkbox-in-php)

These Below code i have used in one of my php page

```
$Qualification=$_SESSION['Qualification']; // gives value = 1,2,3,
        $selectedqualification= explode(",", $Qualification);
        $selectedqualification= array_filter($selected);
```

Now these values are used to bind into checkbox-

```
<?php  $query = "SELECT * FROM Qualification";

  $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>  
<input type='checkbox' value='"<?php $row['Id'] ?> "' name='Qualification[]'  <?php if (in_array($row['Id'], $selectedqualification)){ echo "checked"; } ?> /><?php echo $row['Description'] ?><br>

<?php } ?>
```

The Output of these will be displayed as

```
[/]Teacher
[/]ENgineer
[/]Doctor
[]Banker
```

Where the three values are checked .

Now on submit of the  button using method post in the form

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

   $AllQualification="";

print_r($_POST['Qualification']);

        foreach($_POST['Qualification'] as $Qualification) 
        {
           $AllQualification .=$Qualification.",";
        }
echo $AllQualification

}
```

The output will be

```
Array ( [0] => " " [1] => " " [2] => " " [3] => " ")
'" "," "," "
```

Values are not getting passed to the array. How to get the values to bind to array? Any help appreciated.

Comment: from where `$selectedqualification` came? you have `$selected` variable. do't you think?

Comment: sorry i have updated my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change check-box html like below:-

```
<input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" name='Qualification[]'  <?php if (in_array($row['Id'], $selectedqualification)){ echo "checked"; } ?> /><?php echo $row['Description'] ?><br>
```

CHANGE I MADE (added `echo` and removed single quotes):-

```
value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Man you are missing echo in checkbox value and also space is there:

use this :

```
value='"<?php echo $row['Id'] ?>"'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issue in the code.

1) No echo and use wrong quotes for below, fixed:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php $row['Id'] ?>" name="Qualification[]"  <?php if (in_array($row['Id'], $selectedqualification)){ echo "checked"; } ?> /><?php echo $row['Description'] ?><br>
```

2) Use `implode`, rather than concatenating it.

```
$qualification = implode(",",$_POST['Qualification']);
```

PS: Don't forget to add a check if the array is empty or not.

Hope this helps.